# When adding layers to pre-trained CNN, are you adding to the start or the back. Is it like a queue or a stack?

Tags: machine-learning, stack, queue, transfer-learning

Just a quick question for which I could not quickly find an answer on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing transfer learning, you almost always add layers at the end (towards the output layer) or retrain only the layers at the end. The lower layers usually learn basic features from the data and the higher layers learn more complex features that are more related to the task. This is the case for CNN but also other neural networks.